# Stream audio to Dialogflow with chunks from browser

Tags: node.js, socket.io, dialogflow-es, mediastream

We're doing some experimenting with Dialogflow and we've run into a complete stop for the time being. We're trying to set up a browser client that streams audio in chunks to Dialogflow via the node v2beta1 version of the dialogflow npm package. We followed the example to get it running and it works fine when we use the node server to pick up the sound via extra software (sox), but we want to stream from the browser. So we've set up a small code snippet that picks up the MediaStream from the mic.

When the data event is triggerend we get a chunk (an arraybuffer) that we, in chunks, pass to our node server.

On the server we've followed this example: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/detect-intent-stream#detect-intent-text-nodejs. The only thing we do different is instead of using pump to chain streams, we just write our chunks to the sessionsClient.

```
streamingDetectIntent().write({ inputAudio: [chunk] })
```

During experimentation we received several errors that we solved. But at this point we pass our chunks and receive empty responses, during and at the end.

Is this a valid way of passing audio to dialogflow, or do we really need to set up a stream? We do not want to use the node server as an entry, it needs to be the browser. We will have full control.

Client

```
import getUserMedia from 'get-user-media-promise';
import MicrophoneStream from 'microphone-stream';

export const startVoiceStream = () => {
  const microphoneStream = new MicrophoneStream();

    getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: true })
    .then(function(micStream) {

      microphoneStream.setStream(micStream);

      socket.emit('startMicStream');

      state.streamingMic = true;

      setTimeout(() => {
        // Just closing the stream on a timer for now
        socket.emit('endMicStream');
      }, 5000);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

    microphoneStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    if (state.streamingMic) {
      socket.emit('micStreamData', chunk);
    }
  });
};
```

Server code is much longer so I think I'll spare the details, but these are the main parts.

```
const initialStreamRequest = {
    session: sessions.sessionPath,
    queryParams: {
        session: sessions.sessionPath, //TODO: try to delete
    },
    queryInput: {
        audioConfig: {
            audioEncoding: 'AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16',
            sampleRateHertz: '16000',
            languageCode: 'en-US',
        },
        singleUtterance: false
    },
};

const startRecognitionStream = socketClient => {
    streamIntent = sessions.sessionClient
      .streamingDetectIntent()
      .on('error', error => {
        console.error({ error });
        socketClient.emit('streamError', error);
      })
      .on('data', data => {
        socketClient.emit('debug', { message: 'STREAM "ON DATA"', data });
        if (data.recognitionResult) {
          socketClient.emit(
            'playerTranscript',
            data.recognitionResult.transcript,
          );
          console.log(
            `#Intermediate transcript : ${data.recognitionResult.transcript}`,
          );
        } else {
          socketClient.emit('streamAudioResponse', data);
        }
      });
    streamIntent.write(initialStreamRequest);
  };

socket.on('micStreamData', data => {
    if (streamIntent !== null) {
      stop = true;
      streamIntent.write({ inputAudio: data });
    }
  });
```